# python version 2.7.8 can't run /usr/bin/easy_install. Try the alternative(s):

Tags: macos, homebrew, macports, python, fink

I'm doing a bunch of python development and also just updated OS to Mountain Lion.

I had replaced to original Python versions with Snow Leopard using the GUI from Python.org, then added links in /usr/bin:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  71 Oct 22 18:12 python -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

So now I have what I think are all the python version that are part of OSX 10.8.5 (2.5, 2.6, 2.7) located in:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
```

and linked from `/usr/bin`

And ALSO the ones I installed with the GUI located in:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
```

But I'm planning to use the versions I install with `fink`, which is a port tree similar to `macports` which are/will be located in:

```
/sw/bin
```

So I have commented out the `PATH` exports in `~/.bash_profile` that pointed to the non-fink executables:

```
#PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
#export PATH

#PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
#export PATH
```

And added:

```
#  for Fink:
export PATH=$PATH:/sw/bin
. /sw/bin/init.sh
```

I don't totally understand shell scripting yet, but `init.sh` initializes fink, I think mostly by adding elements to $PATH and other environment variables.

Previously I have installed various packages with `homebrew`, `macports` and various GUIs and am hoping to have a more comprehensible environment this time around.

At the moment I need to install `postgreSQL` and a bunch of `python modules` including `pip`, `virtualenv`, `virtualenvironmentwrapper`, `psycopg`.

It looks like the `easy_install` executable (binary executable?) lives (alongside easy_install-2.5, 2.6 and 2.7) in `/usr/bin/`.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any reason to have more than one copy of each version of Python?
2. Will python-dependent applications work as long as there's a link in `/usr/bin/` to a working, executable python library, and the location of the Python executable is in the `$PATH`?
3. Is there much reason to keep `Python2.5` at this point?
4. `sudo easy_install-2.7 pip` worked, so what exactly is `-rwxr-xr-x   2 root        wheel       925 Oct 23 14:48 easy_install` for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.

Answer to number 1 is yes.

The fink developers recommend NOT removing the OSX versions of Python, simply because they are not terribly large files and may be necessary for certain OSX functions and programs.

And I want to have an additional version of at least python2.7 installed by fink, because it's a port tree that's designed to create a UNIX-like directory structure, which will hopefully make PostgreSQL and python play nicely together.

As far as question number 2, I'm not sure. I *think* this would work, but leaving the original OSX versions installed avoids the issue.

Question 3: yes. - see answer to question 1.

Making the `fink` version the one that runs via the terminal is a matter of:

1. make sure the directory containing the fink python binary precedes the OSX (or GUI-installed one) in the `PATH`, which can be done in users `.profile` or `.bash_profile` (located in directory `~/`, the user's root) by either invoking the fink init script, `. /sw/bin/init.sh`, OR making sure that `export PATH=/sw/bin:$PATH` is included in the file AFTER any other line that exports a `PATH` with one of the other python paths at the beginning. For example, `export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH` or `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`.
2. Unless we want to invoke the python cli like `python2.7`, we'll need to make a symbolic link in the `/sw/bin` directory that points "python" to "python2.7", which is done by using `sudo ln -s *source* *link*`, which in this case looks like:

   sudo ln -s /sw/bin/python2.7 /sw/bin/python

Not sure what the answer to question 4 is yet, but am seeing that any libraries that exist in `/sw/bin` are being called from there, as opposed to other installations. Good.

Got a copy of Learning UNIX for OS X Mountain Lion that looks quite promising.